# Why is there a white area when I open the soft keyboard on cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a Cordova app, but I have some problem with the Android soft keyboard and inputs located on the bottom of the page. Before replying me with links and message that this is a question already asked please finish to read this one.
On the AndroidManifest.xml I wrote this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

So now everytime I touch an inputbox on the bottom the page is scrolled and the keyboard shows up; unfortunately when it scrolls it leaves a big white area:

[image: soft keyboard activated]

The area disappears and the page is scrolled only when at least 2 characters are typed in.
What is the problem? How could I avoid the white area and simply get the page scrolled?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Was there any progress in this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` fixed it for me